# Flutter persistent login

Tags: authentication, flutter, persistence, persistent-storage

I am trying to login a user using a django backend. This works fine and I saved a token and email address combination with the `shared_preferences` package. The package however recommends not to store sensitive information, which the token obviously is. I want to stay logged in until I log out of the app.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage 
A Flutter plugin to store data in secure storage: 
Keychain is used for iOS 
AES encryption is used for Android

code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create storage
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value 
String value = await storage.read(key: key);

// Read all values
Map<String, String> allValues = await storage.readAll();

// Delete value 
await storage.delete(key: key);

// Delete all 
await storage.deleteAll();

// Write value 
await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
```