# Flutter-web persistent login

Tags: flutter, authentication, basic-authentication, flutter-web, persistent-storage

[Some time ago I asked the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248893/flutter-persistent-login) but for iOS and Android. Now that flutter enable web-support, I would like to achieve the same thing. The problem is that the plugin `flutter_secure_storage` is not supported for web. I've searched but not found any alternatives for this. I'd hate to type in my password every time I want to login. I do not know a lot about security so I have no idea where to start and which practices are considered good or bad. I'd be thankful for a few hints in the right direction.

Comment: Shared Preferences may help you

Comment: I'm too paranoid for that. Credentials can be stolen through that.

Comment: You can try encrypted box from hive. Hive has support for flutter web.

Comment: @AbhilashChandran Hive does not seem to persistently save data. Either that or I am doing something wrong with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Hive uses IndexDb to store information and indexDB in browsers are domain locked. Meaning you cannot access db created in one domain from another domain. And the domain includes your port from which the app is being served. So when you run flutter web in debug mode it will always use a new port. Try something like `flutter run -d chrome --web-port 8080`. This will ensure you use same port between debug launch. When deployed in production the domain will be always same and it should work as you expect.

**Update 21.01.2021**
Right now I don't have time to verify this. Maybe this [biometric_storage package](https://pub.dev/packages/biometric_storage/example) could help as it claims to work in web as well.

An example implementation is available [here](https://github.com/jda258/hive_secure_key/blob/master/lib/main.dart) and the corresponding article is [here](https://medium.com/@joshua.akers/storing-hive-encryption-keys-in-flutter-47a7c037d637).

Comment: encrypted box uses secure_storage which is not supported by the web.

Comment: The site of `biometric_storage_package` says the following: `Web: Warning Uses unauthenticated, unencrypted storage in localStorage. If you have a better idea for secure storage on web platform, please open an Issue.`